# Sample application for asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have worked on asp.net 2.0 years ago and recently worked on SL and WPF applicaiton have idea on mvvm. As my next project would be on  ASP.net  MVC DotNet FW 3.5, I was looking for sample application code using MVC any links\forum on this would be of gr8 help.

Welll I was going through http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3 and noticed the view uses cshtml file extension rather aspx and was confused. Please, point  me to some refernces to start as a biggner.

Comment: try http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness.
The Webforms view engine remains which you know as the ASPX extension. With ASP.NET MVC 3, the Razor View Engine was introduced. The syntax is clean, and supposed to be easy to learn.

Answer (score 1):

First of all i'd recommend MVC4 and .Net 4.

The easiest way to learn is create a new project using the default MVC 4 internet project template. It has all the basics covered.

The most important about MVC is that you forget about webpages being files on disk. The .aspx and .cshtml files in MVC are views returned by a controller. A controller is a class which has functions, called Actions in MVC terms. If you have an url `/Home/Index` MVC would call function Index in controller class Home.

Answer (score 0):

The `.cshtml` extension is used by view template files rendered by the ASP.Net MVC3 [Razor View Engine](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-3/mvc-3-razor-view-engine).  I often find videos to be great introductions to topics about which I want to learn more.